DataTable Column Value as Variable to another DataTable
How can i give a column variable out of a datatable to another datatable ?
I have a datatable and if i click a column opens a new datatable with data based of the first datatable.
var table1 = new $('#table1').DataTable( {
    ajax: {            
        url: "index.php?ctr=ajax&action=data",

columns: [
    { data: 'git_id', visible: false, sortable: false, type: "num" },
    { data: 'git_name', visible: true, sortable: true, type: "string" },
    { data: 'git_description', visible: true, sortable: false, type: "string" },

$('#table1 tbody').on('click', 'tr td:nth-child(13)', function () {
    $('#modal-commit').modal('show');
});

var table2 = new $('#table2').DataTable( {
    ajax: {            
        url: "index.php?ctr=commit&action=data",
        type: "POST",
        data: function (d) {
            d.pr_id = "187"; // this should be the value from the clicked row / col of the main datatable
        },

Thank you
UPDATE 19.07.2024
SOLUTION


var table2 = new $('#table2').DataTable( {
    ajax: {            
        url: "index.php?ctr=commit&action=data",
        type: "POST",
        data: { prid: table.cell(this,0).data() }

$data = testRepository::getData($_POST['prid']);


It is great that you found a solution - but please don't add it to the question. Instead, write a separate answer (and delete the solution from the question). See Can I answer my own question? Also, when you write your answer, it may be helpful for future visitors if you provide some notes explaining how/why the answer actually solves your problem. Adding a link to any relevant official documentation may also be useful. See [answer].
